# HyperSQL performance in relation with number of parallel connections

Tags: java, performance, hsqldb, hypersql

Harware setup:

CPU: Intel i5-8 core machine
Memory: 16 GB
Disk: SSD

DB: HyperSQL 2.6.0 (JDK 8)
(Running HyperSQL as a docker container with no extra config, running default config)

Test scenario:
In-Memory Table with 40 cols and 413,000 rows with index on 4 cols (not combined)

Running a java client which simulates 1200 queries executing in a fixed thread pool of size 120. So 1 thread executing 120 requests in a loop OR 120 queries executing in parallel.
Type of queries:

```
select x,y,sum(z),count(distinct a) 
from table 
where b like '%val%' 
  and c != 'val' 
  and d is not null 
group by x,y 
order by sum(z) desc 
limit 100
```

The avg response time is measured at the end of execution and this metric is dependent on the number of connections present in the connection pool. The readings are given in the below table.
Here the Avg is mean not median

| Connection pool size | Avg Response time per query | Avg pool wait time for connection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 14 secs | 0.3 secs |
| 50 | 10 secs | 9 secs |
| 25 | 2.8 secs | 5.7 secs |
| 20 | 2.3 secs | 6.1 secs |
| 15 | 2 secs | 7.2 secs |

But in the HyperSQL [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlPerformance.html), there is a statement where it says that the performance should not be dependent on the number of parallel connections

**HyperSQL is fully multi threaded. If the vast majority of operations are read operations, then performance is very high in all transaction models. Multiple processes, each running in a different thread, can access the same tables or rows at the same time and return the results independently to the user's application(s).**

Can someone please explain this behavior and ways to improve the query performance even when there are higher number of connections to the HyperSQL DB.

Comment: So your computer has 8 cores and you are surprised that running 500 queries in parallel is slower than running 15?

Comment: Sorry a correction, this behavior is present even on a 32 core server.

Comment: Same problem: you are running way more threads that the system has cores.

Comment: The question is, why does it have an impact on the query response times ?

Comment: Is it because the DB Server not getting enough CPU to process the query, since it is busy serving the requests ?

Comment: Not related to the number of concurrent queries, you could improve the actual query speed by using an indexable condition such as `e=val` that uses an index. In its present form it doesn't, therefore all 413000 rows are checked during query execution.

Comment: In the SQL mentioned in question except the col b in where clause cols c and d are indexed.

Comment: The condition `c != 'val'` is not indexable, only `x='val'` is. The `d is not null` uses an index but probably most of the values in d are not null, so it doesn't help much.